# How to delete a post from a dropdown in php

Tags: drop-down-menu, sql-delete

I have a form to deleting posts with dropdown select list. but delete is not working,
it was deleted but when i go and have a look it is not working. Any thoughts?

index.php

```
$delete = $_POST['delete_submit'];

    mysql_query("DELETE FROM posts WHERE Post_id=$delete");
?>
 <section style="font-size: 22px; text-align: center;">
        <form action='check.php' method='post' onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to 

delete this post?');">
            <p>
                Delete Post:&nbsp;
                <select name="delete">
                    <option>Please select a post</option>
                    <?php
                    $result = mysql_query("SELECT Post_id, Post_title FROM posts ORDER BY Post_id 

DESC");
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                        $blogvar  = array($row ['Post_id'], $row ['Post_title']);
                    ?>
                    <option><?php echo $blogvar[1]; ?></option>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
                <p></p>
                <input type='submit' class='button' name='submit' value='Delete'/>
            </p>
        </form>
    </section>
```

and

check.php

```
include "base.php";


    mysql_query("DELETE FROM posts WHERE post_id =$_POST['delete']")
```

Thank you

Comment: Please provide some code, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many things wrong here, but anyway...

1. The SQL in your `check.php` file should actually delete all posts because you're comparing the `post_id` field to itself in SQL.
2. You actually need to reference the submitted value from your form, you've named your select `delete` so that should be `$_POST['delete']` - but read on, your errors don't end there.
3. You've named your submit button the same as your select field, that second element named `delete` will mask the first meaning that no matter what you select the value of `$_POST['delete']` will always be 'Delete', you need to change one of the names.
4. Including variables directly in strings that you execute against your DB opens you up to what's called an "SQL Injection Attack" - google it.

#### Update

The OP has edited his sample code now making everything except my last point nonsensical.  No idea if the problem still exists.

#### Another Update

I missed another error:

1. You have the `<option>`s of your select without any `value` attribute, which means that your `post_id` is not actually being submitted as the value of your `delete` select element.

Comment: the problem still exists.what i can do?

Comment: I updated my answer again, should be #5